# SceneKit. How to set supersampling to 2x programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos, 3d, scenekit

In the UI of the scene settings in SceneKit there is supersampling option and it is 1x by default. How to set it to 2x programatically?[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry semyon, the IDE is not Xcode, right?

Comment: It’s AppCode on the screenshot. But when I build the project with XCode it’s the same. IDE doesn’t matter. Those settings are default SceneKit settings.

Comment: Are you sure it is Apple's SceneKit? I installed AppCode and found it cannot edit `*.scn` file extension.

Comment: Ok. I uploaded screenshot from the same project, opened with XCode